# How to use WebKit browser control in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, webkit

I want to use WebKit browser control in my WPF application. However, I am not able to add it in design time. Even if I add the WebKit into toolbox it is disabled state.

My question is how to use that control during design time on WPF form?

Thanks,
Omkar

Comment: [A Real WPF 4.0 WebBrowser](http://chriscavanagh.wordpress.com/2010/10/04/a-real-net-4-0-webbrowser/)

Answer (score 2):

As explained in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742735(v=vs.110).aspx , you should first create a WPF grid in your XAML file.

```
<Grid x:Name="grdBrowserHost">
</Grid>
```

And add a .NET WebKit in the WPF form by inserting this code into your C# source.

```
System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost host =new System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost();

// Create the ActiveX control.
WebKit.WebKitBrowser browser = new WebKit.WebKitBrowser();
browser.Navigate("http://www.google.com");

// Assign the ActiveX control as the host control's child.
host.Child = browser;

// Add the interop host control to the Grid 
// control's collection of child controls. 
grdBrowserHost.Children.Add(host);
```

Do not forget to include these references

```
System.Windows.Forms

WindowsFormsIntegration
```

in your project.

Hope this help.

Comment: This has the unfortunate result of running WebKit within a separate hWnd via the `WindowsFormsHost` which is then reparented inside the WPF context - which adds many layers of indirection that will harm performance and may not be usable under High-DPI conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it's an activex control. Try this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742735.aspx

Answer (score 0):

One of the best approaches for hosting Webkit (or Blink) in a WPF application presently 
(as of October 2017) seems to be with [the Awesomium project](http://wiki.awesomium.net) which has first-class wrapper libraries for various platforms, including WinForms and WPF.

I advise against using any web-browser control inside a `System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost` in a WPF application because, at least, of the added layers of indirection and unpredictable behaviour in High-DPI contexts - I'm sure there are other reasons too.

Note that Awseomium is not true open-source or Free Software. [If your company makes more than $100k USD in profit per year then for commercial applications there is a $2900 USD per-title license fee](http://wiki.awesomium.com/licensing/licensing-overview.html).

With that caveat out the way, [getting started with Awesomium in WPF is straightforward](http://wiki.awesomium.net/getting-started/setting-up-on-windows):

1. [Download the Awesomium SDK](http://www.awesomium.com/download/). (As of October 2017 the Awesomium download page is unavailable for an upgrade, [but the SDK is still available to download from the Internet Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20170311013220/http://www.awesomium.com/download/) and other places online).
2. The SDK installer will register the Awesomium assemblies in the GAC for you, so they'll appear in the WPF (and WinForms) Toolbox Add/Remove Items window.
3. Open your WPF project in Visual Studio and open a XAML design document.
4. Open the Visual Studio Toolbox and open the Add/Remove Items window and add the Awesomeium WPF controls from the `Awesomium.Windows.Controls.dll` assembly loaded in your GAC. You'll probably only want the `WebControl` control (`Awesomium.Windows.Controls.WebControl`).
5. Drag and drop the control from the Toolbox onto your design surface - Visual Studio will automatically update your project to add the references to the Awesomeium assemblies.

Note there are other wrapper libraries around Chromium - I don't meant to endorse Awesomium specifically, but I had a good time with it when I used it in a recent project.

Another popular library is [CefSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp) which is BSD licensed, which will be more palatable compared to Awesomium's, but (as far as I can tell) does not distribute an SDK installer which handles Visual Studio Toolbox integration for you - but it looks like you only need to manually add a reference to the `CefSharp.Wpf.dll` assembly and add the elements to your WPF project (using the XAML editor, not the Toolbox - which you should be doing anyway).